# Expected comma json(514)

Tags: json, visual-studio

so i am having a very strange issue with vs code that In my json package.json I am getting an error i.e expected comma json(514) none of my search helped any idea about it

Code-

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "next build",
    "prettier": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Error-

```
Expected comma json(514) [5,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `"start": "next start"`

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "next build",
    "prettier": "prettier --write .",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```